# How to store and handle JWT tokens on front-end using fetch, and how to store it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, authentication, jwt

I am new to development, I have a task manager app in which I am using JWT tokens to verify, I can make it work on Postman, but I couldn't figure out how to store it through a browser and send it to server.

Here is what I am trying to do to make it work, but it says undefined outside the event listener, and I couldn't store the token to later send it to another url, I am sending the token to an API.

Here is my front end app.js code, for login page, on login the user is sent a JWT token :

```
let inMemoryToken;


const signInForm = document.querySelector( "#sign-in-form" );
signInForm.addEventListener( "submit", ( e ) => {
    const email = document.querySelector( "#login-email" ).value;
    const password = document.querySelector( "#login-pass" ).value;
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log( email, password );
    fetch( "http://localhost:3000/users/login", {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify( {

            "email": email,
            "password": password,

        } )
    } ).then( res => res.json() )
        .then( res => {
            console.log( res );
            let inMemoryToken = res.token;
            console.log( inMemoryToken );
            // { Authorization: `Bearer  ${ inMemoryToken }`; }
            return inMemoryToken;
        } );

    console.log( inMemoryToken );

    
 return inMemoryToken;
} );
// inMemoryToken = res.body.token[ 0 ];
// let inMemoryToken2 = inMemoryToken;

console.log( inMemoryToken );
```

My back-end code for the log in is :

```
router.post( "/users/login", async ( req, res ) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(
            req.body.email,
            req.body.password
        );
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken();
        res.send( {
            user,
            token,
        } );
    } catch ( e ) {
        res.status( 400 ).send( {
            error: "Catch error",
            e,
        } );
    }
} );
```

Also, after getting this token, I want to pass this to my tasks url, which is as :

```
const TaskForm = document.querySelector( "#add-tasks" );
TaskForm.addEventListener( "submit", ( e ) => {
    const task = document.querySelector( '#task' ).value;
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log( task );
    console.log( inMemoryToken );

    fetch( "http://localhost:3000/tasks/", {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ${inMemoryToken}'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify( {

            "Task": task

        } )
    } ).then( res => res.json() )
        .then( res => console.log( res ) );
} );
```

I have been trying to solve this from 3 days, and couldn't get it to work, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To store JWT on client you have two options: `Cookies` or `LocalStorage` strategies. I guess that you already know what a cookie is. LocalStorage is quite similar to a cookie, but enhanced and without sending information in headers (see [Mozilla Developer definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)), that's why LocalStorage is usually applied as persistant object.

**Server** side remains as you already have. No changes are needed.

On your client, in the **handler of login** response, you will store in LocalStorage your response from backend, like this:

```js
signInForm.addEventListener( "submit", ( e ) => {
  . . .
  fetch( "http://localhost:3000/users/login", {
    . . .
  } ).then( res => res.json() )
       .then( res => {
          console.log( res );
          let inMemoryToken = res.token;

          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(res));
          // 'user' is the generic key to sotre in LocalStorage. You could use any name you want
          // Store complete object, so you will be able to access 'user' and 'token' later
```

On your **task function**, you should read LocalStorage for your object

```js
const TaskForm = document.querySelector( "#add-tasks" );
TaskForm.addEventListener( "submit", ( e ) => {
    const task = document.querySelector( '#task' ).value;
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log( task );
    
    // ------ This is what you have to add --------
    const localstorage_user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
    const inMemoryToken = localstorage_user.token
    // -------------------------------------------

    console.log( inMemoryToken );
```

Comment: Couldn't thank you enough, I was really struggling to figure this out. Big thanks.

Also, can you give me an idea of why my authorization passing is not working in this code : 
https://jsfiddle.net/mx7cg03w/1/

Comment: If you found it useful, accept the answer :-) What is your additional problem? No code is provided on your comment? Are your referring to your question's code?

Comment: Sorry, your link was not displaying. I'll take a look

Comment: Sorry, I have now added the code on jsfiddle, can you please give it a look.

Comment: Mmm. I think is the `'` character. Try: ``Bearer ${inMemoryToken}``

Comment: No you are right, It's the apostrophe ' character, I am trying with double quotes and will get back to you in a minute.

Comment: I've updated your code. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/mL0t834j/ There is the char you should be using (I cannot post becasue is higlighted).

Comment: This is not working, its giving me the error : 
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ app-js.js:101

Comment: Hard to say. There is no `T` on your code. What is on that file: `app-js.js`, line 101?

Comment: .then( res => console.log( res ) ); This is on 101 line, yeah, there is no T, This is sort of a general error it throws, when it can't identify the error

https://jsfiddle.net/w6tepsb5/ : Here is the full code again, if you can give it a look to figure out

Comment: Are you sure that, in `.then( res => res.json() )`, `res` is actually a JSON file?? Maybe te problem is there. Try only with the `console.log()` to minimally debug.

Comment: The code for that is : 
`try {
  await task.save();
  res.status(201).send("Task saved: " + task);
 }`

And on only `console.log()` its giving the same error

Also the line 100 and 101 collectively is : `.then( res => res.json() )
        .then( res => console.log() );
} );`

Comment: I just checked that the task is being stored in the database, just it's not console printing the response correctly.

Comment: Your are sending a basic string, and you want to parse it as a JSON. I think there is why it is cracking. Do something like `res.status(200).send( { message: "Task saved:"+task } )`, to force sending JSON response

Comment: Perfect. Have fun programming :)

Comment: Hi @Sergio, Can you please give my this query a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587902/how-to-upload-image-using-multer-through-browser

or this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63588833/how-to-pass-parameter-in-url-with-a-colon-in-the-javascript-server-side-for-nod

Thanks a lot again.