# How to pass parameter in url, with a colon in the javascript server side for NodeJS backend?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, url-parameters

I am trying to pass a numeric id as a parameter in the URL to the server. What am I doing wrong?

I have a task manager app in which to read a task, users can read a task by its id, now I am passing this directly in postman by entering id (5e8b) as:

`{{url}}/tasks/5e8b`

But I couldn't make it work in the browser, here is my Html code :

```
<h1>Read Task by Task ID</h1>
    <form id="task-id-form">
        <input type="text" id="task-id"><br> <br>
        <button id="task-id-button">Find Task</button>
        <p id="task-id-display"></p>
    </form>
```

And my server-side JS code is (which is not working) :

```
const readTaskForm = document.querySelector( "#task-id-form" );
readTaskForm.addEventListener( "submit", ( e ) => {
    const readTaskId = document.querySelector( "#task-id" ).value;
    const params = { id: readTaskId }; // new addition
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams( Object.entries( readTaskId ) );

    fetch( "http://localhost:3000/tasks/" + urlParams, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Bearer` + `${ inMemoryToken }`
        }
    } ).then( res => res.json() )
        .then( res => {
            console.log( res );
           
        }
        );
} );
```

And my backend node js code is as (which is working correctly in postman ):

```
router.get( "/tasks/:id", auth, async ( req, res ) => {
    const _id = req.params.id;
    try {
        const task = await Task.findOne( { _id, owner: req.user._id } );
        if ( !task ) {
            return res.status( 401 ).send( { error: "Task id not found" } );
        }
        res.send( { task } );
    } catch ( e ) {
        res.status( 400 ).send( e );
    }
} );
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you form your URL like this: '{{url}}/tasks/id=5e8b' what happens?

Comment: Sorry, the url in the browser is as : localhost:3000/tasks/5e8b

Comment: I don't think it works with id=5e8b

Comment: sorry, yes I need to re-read your question

Comment: please define "not working" and "make it work". what specific behavior is exhibited and what error messages are you seeing in your browser tools or in your server console?

Comment: Before you call the fetch method; is the value of the urlParams const the value of the task-id input?

Comment: Hi @DanO, what I am expecting to do is to pass the input from HTML form to the server to pass it in url as my backend is expecting, but the input is not getting passed and thus nothing is hapeening, while I expect the input id to be sent through it, and on backend using that Id I want to send the task with that specific id.

Comment: Hi @JakeB. I have updated the params code, and I cannot figure out how to pass that parameter input I am receiving, I know I couldn't explain it well, but please give your best shot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to use **URLSearchParams** as a parameter, simply use **readTaskId**

```
        const readTaskForm = document.querySelector("#task-id-form");
        readTaskForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
          const readTaskId = document.querySelector("#task-id").value;
          //const params = { id: readTaskId }; // new addition

          //const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(Object.entries(readTaskId));
          fetch("http://localhost:3000/tasks/" + readTaskId, {
            method: "get",
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Authorization: `Bearer` + `${inMemoryToken}`
            }
          })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((res) => {
              console.log(res);
            });
        });
```

Comment: It's throwing error - 400 Bad request at line 

` fetch( "http://localhost:3000/tasks/" + readTaskId, { `

Comment: are you setting the slash at the end of "tasks"?  ` fetch( "localhost:3000/tasks/" + readTaskId, { ` . show us an alert or a console.log of the final url (with the parameter too)

Comment: Yes I am putting the slash in the end of the URL as `fetch( "http://localhost:3000/tasks/" + readTaskId, {`

and I have my route  at the backend as: `router.get( "/tasks/:id", auth, async ( req, res ) => {`

Also, your Blahbox website is well designed :)

Comment: Thanks about Blahbox!. You should send us more information about the error. Complete console error, some screenshoot.... Maybe your header is having some issue.

Comment: Hi Matias, here is a screenshot of the console: https://ibb.co/gVdrczb

Comment: Also, the code on line 199 is: https://ibb.co/8BsPMpc

Comment: now I think you have problems in this line: `const task = await Task.findOne( { _id, owner: req.user._id } ); `

Comment: What could be the problem here? I am getting an error on authentication if I am running the authentication, and if I don't I am getting the above error. 

Though this code is working perfectly in postman.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you again, but do you have any suggestions on my last comment